# How to define custom enum values in swagger

Tags: java, swagger

How could I create an Enum that fields are different from their values using swagger.yml?

Example, generating an Enum with these fields:

ON("1"),
OFF("0");

Instead of:

ON("ON"),
OFF("OFF");

Comment: Added vote up to you , because , question is impressive

Answer (score 0):

**To get idea how to add Enum to swagger.yml**

```
swagger: swagger version 
info:
  title:  Enum added to yml
  version: "swagger version of your application"
host: dulaj.kulathunga
schemes:
  - https
basePath: /1
produces:
  - application/atom+xml
paths:
  /demo:
    get:
      summary: enum added to yml samples
      description: |
        enum added to yml samples
      parameters:
        - name: switch_status
          in: query
          description: switech preperties
          required: true
          type: string
          enum:
            - On
            - Off

      responses:
        200:
          description: The response upon succesful query
        default:
          description: Error occured
```

Comment: I would like to define enum aspects inside swagger.yml file. Creating a Java file manualy is not an option for me.

Comment: This ones does not create a Enum with fields ON("1"), OFF("0");. It creates   TRUE("true"),  FALSE("false");